# cant insert data from forms into mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can anyone explain why this insert is not working?

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    $query = 'INSERT INTO subsciber(data, ip, email) 
          VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'", "'.$_POST['email'].'")';
    $result =  @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
}
```

And forms code looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm6-6 col-sm-offset-3 ">
         <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                <input name='email' id="email" type="email" class="form-control transparent" placeholder="Your email here...">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name='send' value='send' class="btn btn-danger btn-fill">Notify Me</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the error that is returned

Comment: Show us `$dbc`. Do you have connection to database? Do you have any value in `$_POST['email']`? Is there any error at all?

Comment: You should ON error reporting in developement mode. Never use @ to hide errors.

Comment: Remove the `@` since it silence's the error and then run it. Check if it is getting inside the if condition

Comment: Perhaps the email contains quotes :/

Comment: remove @ from  @mysqli_query($dbc, $query); to get the exact error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Comment: The problem here is that `data` is a `Reserved Word` that shouldn't be used as a `column name` unless you use `backticks`.

Comment: Try to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to insert special characters in the database.

Comment: @Irvin nothing here is a reserved word

Comment: @Drew His column `data`. My bad, it is a `Keyword` not a `Reserved Word`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: @KinjalMistry No, he should use a prepared query and `bind_param`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include `mysqli` `error` `function` to see your errors

```
    if(isset($_POST['send'])){
        $query = 'INSERT INTO subsciber(data, ip, email) 
              VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'", "'.$_POST['email'].'")';
//echo $query; to see query output
        $result =  mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
    }
```

Also `data` is mysqli `keyword` so use `backtick` around this

```
 $query = 'INSERT INTO subsciber(`data`, ip, email) 
                  VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'", "'.$_POST['email'].'")';
```

Comment: It's a keyword, but it's not reserved.

Answer (score -1):

Your form does not have an action property:

Do this:

```
<form action="the url to your PHP script">
```

Comment: The default is to use the same URL as the page itself.

Comment: If the PHP script is in the same file as the HTML form

Answer (score -2):

Replace

```
@mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

with

```
mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Comment: That won't help. `mysqli_query()` doesn't report MySQL errors automatically, you have to print `mysqli_error($dbc)`.

Answer (score -2):

instead of single quotation you can use doublequotation

Try This one

```
if(isset($_POST["send"])) {
    .....
}
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference? There's nothing in `send` that behaves differently depending on the type of quotes.

Comment: i have faced same problem one time then  i changed single quotation to  doublequotation it working fine

Comment: It must have been some other problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php